# Prepend text to outputted file

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk

I would like to parse through a document, breaking up each "Part" section into an individual file. Im using the following script to do this:

`awk 'BEGIN {RS="Part [0-9]\n";} {F=sprintf("test_%03d", NR); print > F; close(F)}' text.txt`

But, I want the outputted text to be printed in the following format for each file:

```
title, author, part, text
politics, aristotle, 1, <outputted text goes here>
```

where title and author are fixed, part is a number that increases from 1 to *n* the number of parts there are, and outputted text last.

I'm stuck in this part: `print > F;` looking over the [gnu docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html) it seems that what i want is something like `print | printf("title,author,part,text\npolitics,aristotle,%d,%s", counter, F)` (excuse my c-like syntax here). Where the result of the field is piped into a printf statement.

Thanks!

Comment: There's no such piping, instead use the _value_ that you want printed, which is the current record, $0: `printf "headings\npolitics,aristotle,%d,%s",counter,$0 >F`

Comment: thanks! this is simpler and much more elegant than what i was thinking. Can you please add it as the answer? thanks